# Почему редакторы издательств "не любят" букву "Ё"?

Tags: редактура

Если открывать литературу, прошедшую через различные издательства, то можно поймать себя на мысли, что любое слово с буквой "ё" в составе будет изменено в написании - она будет заменена в тексте буквой "е". Почему так происходит и есть ли "официальная" регламентация, считающая это "правильным"?

Comment: Не могу сослаться на "официальную" информацию, так что комментарий. Слышал, что ноги растут из банальной лени наборщиков, которым "далеко тянуться". Потом подключилась стандартизация. Приходилось слышать оправдания в стиле " с Ё тяжелее читается" (почему? это не ко мне), а у нас, как известно, читателя любят щадить, жалеть и боятся оскорбить: длинными предложениями, сложными текстами... и вот буквой Ё, как оказалось тоже. Зато орфографическими ошибками и халтурной писаниной, надо полагать, издательства оскорбить никого не боятся.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Почему редакторы издательств “не любят” букву “Ё”?
```

Они не букву не любят, они просто следуют правилам, а правила закреплены в академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2006), одобренном Орфографической комиссией РАН.

Там четко указано, что употребление буквы ё может быть последовательным и выборочным.

> Последовательное употребление обязательно в следующих разновидностях
>   печатных текстов: а) в текстах с последовательно поставленными знаками
>   ударения (к ним относятся в том числе заголовочные слова в словарях и
>   энциклопедиях); б) в книгах, адресованных детям младшего возраста; в)
>   в учебных текстах для школьников младших классов и иностранцев,
>   изучающих русский язык. При этом сделана важнейшая оговорка: по
>   желанию автора или редактора любая книга может быть напечатана
>   последовательно с буквой ё.

В обычных печатных текстах, согласно справочнику, буква ё употребляется выборочно. **Рекомендуется** употреблять ее в следующих случаях:

1) для предупреждения неправильного опознания слова, напр.: всё, нёбо, лётом, совершённый (в отличие соответственно от слов все, небо, летом, совершенный), в том числе для указания на место ударения в слове, напр.: вёдро, узнаём (в отличие от ведро́, узна́ем);

2) для указания правильного произношения слова – либо редкого, недостаточно хорошо известного, либо имеющего распространенное неправильное произношение, напр.: гёзы, сёрфинг, флёр, твёрже, щёлочка, в том числе для указания правильного ударения, напр.: побасёнка, приведённый, унесённый, осуждённый, новорождённый, филёр;

3) в собственных именах – фамилиях, географических названиях, напр.: Конёнков, Неёлова, Катрин Денёв, Шрёдингер, Дежнёв, Кошелёв, Чебышёв, Вёшенская, Олёкма.

Правила выборочного употребления буквы ё стали намного подробнее. В отличие от свода 1956 года, добавлена рекомендация употреблять ё в словах, имеющих распространенное неправильное произношение; кроме того, выделены в отдельный пункт собственные имена, чтобы не было трудностей в паспортных столах и МФЦ.

Вот редакторы и следуют этим правилам и правят тексты в соответствии с ними. Они люди серьёзные. Кстати, ещё и для того, чтобы не давать пищу для затянувшихся споров "ёфикаторов" и их противников. **Чтобы никому не навредить и не навлечь на себя чей-то гнев, лучше писать по правилам.**

Comment: в Вашем  ответе несколько раз сказано о рекомендациях, когда ставить Ё. Но ни разу не сказано о рекомендации НЕ СТАВИТЬ Ё. Поэтому не считаю корректным  ссылаться на формулировку "можно и так, и сяк" для обоснования утверждения "Они не букву не любят, они просто следуют правилам". Букву Ё именно не любят, так как правила нигде не запрещают её свободно употреблять в любом слове (по крайней мере, Вы таковое не привели). Они дают поблажку, но не устанавливают ограничение. Это две разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Не любое слово, а только то, где Ё излишне.
Ё последовательно проставляется (и то с оговорками) в:
1. Именах собственных, особенно иностранных.
2. Словах, где она служит смыслоразличительным маркером (все-всё).
3. Детской и учебной литературе, пособиях РКИ.

Во всех остальных случаях необходимости в Ё нет. Редактор совершенно справедливо удаляет ненужные точки над Ё. Ничего к тексту, кроме излишней пестроты, они не добавляют.

> Азбучная истина № 7. Употребление буквы ё обязательно в текстах с
>   последовательно поставленными знаками ударения, в книгах для детей
>   младшего возраста (в том числе учебниках для школьников младших
>   классов), в учебниках для иностранцев. В обычных печатных текстах ё
>   пишется в тех случаях, когда возможно неправильное прочтение слова,
>   когда надо указать правильное произношение редкого слова или
>   предупредить речевую ошибку. Букву ё следует также писать в
>   собственных именах. В остальных случаях употребление ё факультативно,
>   т. е. необязательно.

http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99537/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Answer (score -1):

Традиционно в русском правописании допускается замена буквы «ё» на букву «е».
Целью такой замены является **удобство читателей**, которые «спотыкаются» о выпирающее из привычного ряда букв двоеточие. Предполагается, что читатель, знакомый с правописанием большинства слов русской речи, вполне способен самостоятельно восстановить звук «ё» в соответствующих местах.

Диакритика (надстрочные знаки) доставляет существенный дискомфорт при чтении - можно убедиться, открыв любую книгу с последовательно поставленными знаками ударения (букварь или учебник для иностранцев).

Употребление буквы "ё" до настоящего времени и даже в самые последние годы не получило в печати сколько-нибудь широкого распространения. Это нельзя считать случайным явлением. Сама форма буквы "ё" (буква и две точки над ней) представляет собой несомненную сложность с точки зрения моторной деятельности пишущего: ведь написание этой часто употребляемой буквы требует трех раздельных приемов (буква, точка и точка), причем нужно каждый раз следить за тем, чтобы точки оказались симметрично поставленными над знаком буквы. В общей системе русского письма, почти не знающего надстрочных знаков (у буквы "й" надстрочный знак проще, чем у "ё"), буква "ё" составляет весьма обременительное и, видимо, поэтому не вызывающее к себе симпатии исключение.

Особого внимания требовала буква "ё" и с наступлением компьютерной эпохи. В разных раскладках ё занимает разное место (зачастую – неудобное), на некоторых клавиатурах, выпускавшихся на заре компьютерной эры, она вообще не была предусмотрена, иногда напечатать букву можно было только с помощью специальных символов текстового редактора.

Согласно полному академическому справочнику «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (2006), в обычных печатных текстах буква "ё" употребляется выборочно. Рекомендуется употреблять ее в следующих случаях:
1) для предупреждения неправильного опознания слова, напр.: всё, нёбо, лётом, совершённый (в отличие соответственно от слов все, небо, летом, совершенный), в том числе для указания на место ударения в слове, напр.: вёдро, узнаём (в отличие от ведро́, узна́ем);
2) для указания правильного произношения слова – либо редкого, недостаточно хорошо известного, либо имеющего распространенное неправильное произношение, напр.: гёзы, сёрфинг, флёр, твёрже, щёлочка, в том числе для указания правильного ударения, напр.: побасёнка, приведённый, унесённый, осуждённый, новорождённый, филёр;
3) в собственных именах – фамилиях, географических названиях, напр.: Конёнков, Неёлова, Катрин Денёв, Шрёдингер, Дежнёв, Кошелёв, Чебышёв, Вёшенская, Олёкма.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99535/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-------).

Comment: __Прошу продолжать обсуждение в чате.__

Comment: Если вы поставите @никпользователя, оповещение будет.